# Solution to work disk space not enough in sas

Tags: sas

I have more than 50 tables running in work. Before, it worked well. 
But recently, there are some errors like:

> ERROR: An I/O error has occurred on file
>   WORK.'SASTMP-000000030'n.UTILITY. ERROR: File
>   WORK.'SASTMP-000000030'n.UTILITY is damaged. I/O processing did not
>   complete. NOTE: Error was encountered during utility-file processing.
>   You may be able to execute the SQL statement successfully if you 
>         allocate more space to the WORK library. ERROR: There is not enough WORK disk space to store the results of an internal sorting
>   phase. ERROR: An error has occurred.

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Comment: What SQL statement is generating this line?  How big are the datasets involved?

Answer (score 3):

Your disk is full.  If this is running on a server, ask your system administrator to investigate the problem.

If this is your desktop, find and delete un-needed files to free up space.

**Clean out old SAS Work Folders**

Often, old SAS Work folders do not get cleared when SAS closes.  You can get back a lot of disk space by going to the path defined for SAS Work, and deleting all the old folders.

In SAS

```
%put %sysfunc(pathname(work));
```

will show you where the current WORK library is located.  One level up is where all SAS Work folders are created.

On my system, that returns:

```
C:\Users\dpazzula\AppData\Local\Temp\SAS Temporary Files\_TD9512_GXM2L12-PAZZULA_
```

That means that I should look in "C:\Users\dpazzula\AppData\Local\Temp\SAS Temporary Files\" to find old folders to delete.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, though the OP is not sufficiently clear to know if this is the issue or if the SQL statement might just be getting overly large...

Comment: I based this on the statement that the code was previously running OK.  "Before, it worked well."  But yes, it could be a bad SQL statement that has filled up the HD.

Comment: Good point. Thanks. The SAS crashed happened when I use SQL to do the join. So you mean that it could happen if the joined item is not unique in each of the table. This results in overly large?

Comment: Exactly. That's why @Joe was asking for more details on the join

Answer (score 0):

Your work space is full.
Your SAS server uses a dedicated directory where all SAS sessions store their temporary files: All files in the work libraries, as well as temp files as used while sorting, joining etc.

Solutions:

1. Have more space allocated.
2. Make certain only to put necessary files into work/ clean up/ close old sessions.
3. Run less processes.

Answer (score 0):

Replace interim datasets with views instead, especially if you're using large source datasets :

```
data master /view=master ;
  set lib.monthlydata20: ; /* all datasets since Jan 2000 */
run ;

proc sql ;
  create table want as
  select *
  from master
  where ID in(select ID from lookup) ;
quit ;
```

Comment: If I want to delete table to save some space, do you think I can use Proc datasets library=work  delete tablename  can work?

Comment: I tried to create view. But there is error: SQL View work.tablename could not be processed because at least one of the data sets, or views, referenced directly or indirectly by it could not be located, or opened successfully. What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
try to compress all datasets using this option
OPTIONS COMPRESS=YES REUSE=YES;
this should be in the very beginning of your code. it will compress all datasets by nearly 98%.It will also make your code run faster. It will consume more CPU but will decrease size.
In some cases, this might not help if the compressed data sets exceed the hard disk space.
Also, change your work directory to the biggest drive that has disk space.
```

Answer (score 0):

Study your code.

Create a Data Flow Diagram to determine WHEN each file is created, where it is used downstream. Find out when a data set is no longer needed and DELETE it.  If you have 50 data sets, chances are numerous data sets are 'value-added' by a subsequent step, and can go away freeing up your work space.   A cute trick is to REUSE some of the data set names - to keep the number of unneeded data sets in check.

Rule of thumb: leave the environment the way you found it - if there were no files in WORK to start, manually clean up after yourself.  Unless it is a Stored Process, which starts a completely new SAS job, and will clean up after itself upon completion of the job.